# ImageInput upload base64 pictures

Tags: admin-on-rest

everyone,
I'm using ImageInput in my project:

```
<ImageInput source="pictures" accept="image/*">
  <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
</ImageInput>
```

And by by tutorial I wrapped restclient

```
const uploadCapableClient = addUploadCapabilities(restClient);
```

And it was passed to

```
<Admin restClient={uploadCapableClient}> ... </Admin>
```

And code of `addUploadCapabilities` is

```
const convertFileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
});

const addUploadCapabilities = requestHandler => (type, resource, params) => {
    if (type === 'UPDATE' && resource === 'news') {
        if (params.data.pictures && params.data.pictures.length) {
            // only freshly dropped pictures are instance of File
            const formerPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => !(p instanceof File));
            const newPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => p instanceof File);

            return Promise.all(newPictures.map(convertFileToBase64))
                .then(base64Pictures => base64Pictures.map(picture64 => ({
                    src: picture64,
                    title: `${params.data.title}`,
                })))
                .then(transformedNewPictures => requestHandler(type, resource, {
                    ...params,
                    data: {
                        ...params.data,
                        pictures: [...transformedNewPictures, ...formerPictures],
                    },
                }));
        }
    }

    return requestHandler(type, resource, params);
};

export default addUploadCapabilities;
```

it is full copy-paste from tutorial https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload

it worked some time ago perfectly. and on backend i could see big base64 encode text. but now i see:

```
{"rawFile"=>{"preview"=>"blob:http://admin.dev/8ec17f33-6234-42b2-a40c-bcbfc17d4a99"}, "src"=>"blob:http://admin.dev/8ec17f33-6234-42b2-a40c-bcbfc17d4a99", "title"=>"out.png"}
```

So, can anybody try to update AOR to the last version 1.2.1 and check using `ImageInput` ?

Thank

---

In my opinion problem can start in this lines:

```
// function addUploadCapabilities
const newPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => p instanceof File);
```

No `params.data.pictures` that is `instanceof File` and that's why `convertFileToBase64` function was not called.

I will glad any suggestions. Thanks

---

Thank you all.
This is working code on `admin-on-rest 1.2.1`

```
/**
 * Convert a `File` object returned by the upload input into
 * a base 64 string. That's easier to use on FakeRest, used on
 * the ng-admin example. But that's probably not the most optimized
 * way to do in a production database.
 */
const convertFileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);

    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
});

/**
 * For posts update only, convert uploaded image in base 64 and attach it to
 * the `picture` sent property, with `src` and `title` attributes.
 */
const addUploadCapabilities = requestHandler => (type, resource, params) => {
    if ((type === 'UPDATE' || type === 'CREATE') && resource === 'news') {
        if (params.data.pictures && params.data.pictures.length) {
            // only freshly dropped pictures are instance of File
            const formerPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => !(p.rawFile instanceof File));
            const newPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => p.rawFile instanceof File);

            return Promise.all(newPictures.map(convertFileToBase64))
                .then(base64Pictures => base64Pictures.map(picture64 => ({
                    src: picture64,
                    title: `${params.data.title}`,
                })))
                .then(transformedNewPictures => requestHandler(type, resource, {
                    ...params,
                    data: {
                        ...params.data,
                        pictures: [...transformedNewPictures, ...formerPictures],
                    },
                }));
        }
    }

    return requestHandler(type, resource, params);
};

export default addUploadCapabilities;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addUploadFeature.js, change:

`reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);`

to

```
const formerPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => !(p.rawFile instanceof File));
const newPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => p.rawFile instanceof File);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's probably because of a recent change (can't find the PR though).

Files are transformed [here](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/input/FileInput.js#L91), so you probably want to filter on the `rawFile` property which is an instance of `File`.

I'll create an issue so that we fix the documentation

Comment: thank you so much for response and for your time, but how can i fix it for upload as it was earlier?